# Duplicate the results of fallen objects

Tags: duplicate

I'm working on creating a randomizing process to make different sculptural compositions.  I have created a few abstract shaped (they are the shaped selected). Then I have created a box with some walls inside, the box will not be part of the sculpture it is just there to hold the abstract shapes. I have added gravity to the abstract shapes and place the objects above the box, then I press play to have the objects fall into the box, the box is stationary. I would like to then duplicate the results of the shapes without the box to create many different sculpture ideas or different ways the abstract shapes could fit together. When I select the abstract pieces after they have fallen into the box and try to duplicate them, they duplicate into their original position before they fell. Is there a way to duplicate the results of the fallen abstract pieces. Thanks for your help. Hopefully this wasn’t too confusing.

The photo is of the abstract shapes floating above the box before they fall into in.

Comment: there is no photo...

Answer (score 1):

Before duplicating your object, select the object, choose object->rigid body->apply transformation, then delete the rigid body and then copy it.